# Storing specific words from a file into an array (c)

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, scanf

I'm trying to read a file which contains a table of results, and store the table headings as separate strings in an array. So for example, the table has 6 headings, and I want to store each heading in a field of an array: titles[6]

Having some difficulty. The program either crashes or does not do anything. Here are 2 variations of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
FILE *weatherData = 0;
weatherData = fopen("weatherData.txt", "r");
char str, titles[56];
int i, count;
int Date[32], High[32], Low[32], Precip[32], Snow[32];

if (weatherData == 0)
{
    printf("File did not open. Check code and retry");
}

/* for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    fscanf(weatherData, "%c", titles[i]);
    printf("%c ", titles[i]);
}*/

while (str != '\n')
{
    fscanf(weatherData, "%s", titles);
    printf("%s ", titles);
}
fclose(weatherData);

return 0;
}
```

This code prints an un-ending ammount of 0s...And the marked out code (/**/) just crashes the program. Any help? The problem is definitely with the loop, just can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Lol, spent 3 hours writing this. Then just found a fix 2 minutes after I posted this...

```
for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    fscanf(weatherData, "%s", titles);
    printf("%s   ", titles);
}
printf("\n");
```